# why getting syntax error for this SQL Stored procedure

Tags: sql

I have three tables,

**Table 1**

```
Fruit_Crate_ID (varchar)
Fruit_Crate_Name (varchar)
Fruit_Crate_Size (varchar)
Fruit_Crate_Price (varchar)
```

**Table 2**

```
Fruit_Crate_ID (varchar)
Fruit_Eatable (Bool)
```

**Table 3**

```
Fruit_Crate_ID (integer)
Fruit_ID (integer)
Fruit_Eatable (Bool)
```

Now I need to create a stored procedure that first check,

if **Table 2** is eatable or not by checking against **Fruit_Crate_ID** if it's false then check **Table 3** as if **Fruit_Crate_ID** and **Fruit_ID** are eatable or not.

```
USE [Database Name]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsFruitEatable] 
    @Fruit_Crate_ID int,
    @Fruit_ID int
AS
BEGIN

if ((select Fruit_Eatable from Table2
where  Table1.Fruit_Crate_ID = @Fruit_Crate_ID))
{
   select Fruit_Eatable from Table3
   where  Table3.Fruit_Crate_ID = @Fruit_Crate_ID and Table3.Fruit_ID = @Fruit_ID
}
```

**Update**

I must need to check table 2 first, if it says fruit is not eatable then I must return false regardless of fruit id.

but if table 2 says fruit crate is eatable then i must need to check if fruit itself is eatable or not.

thanks

Comment: ..you have curly braces, which aren't for scoping in T-SQL. Also, you appear to be expecting a boolean result from that expression..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query contains 2 errors:

1. your if is invalid, check if anything is returned by query is done by using `exists`
2. to enter `if` clause you use `begin .. end`

This is correct one:

```
if exists (select Fruit_Eatable from Table2 where  Table2.Fruit_Crate_ID = @Fruit_Crate_ID)
begin
   select Fruit_Eatable from Table3
   where  Table3.Fruit_Crate_ID = @Fruit_Crate_ID and Table3.Fruit_ID = @Fruit_ID
end
```

**Edited query**

```
USE [Database Name]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsFruitEatable] 
    @Fruit_Crate_ID int,
    @Fruit_ID int
AS
BEGIN

  declare @isEatable bit = null

  if exists (select Fruit_Eatable from Table2 t2 where  t2.Fruit_Crate_ID = @Fruit_Crate_ID and t2.Fruit_Eatable = 1)
  begin
     select @isEatable = Fruit_Eatable
     from Table3 t3
     where  t3.Fruit_Crate_ID = @Fruit_Crate_ID and t3.Fruit_ID = @Fruit_ID
  end

  select isnull(@isEatable, 0) as IsFruitEatable
```

Comment: Using NOT EXISTS will force a table scan; probably not an issue here, but could be if the table is very large and/or poorly indexed.

Comment: will this stored procedure returns false as well if fruit crate is not eatable ? thanks a lot :-)

Comment: I saw that post was updated and it is more clear what result should look like. Reverted it back to `exists` only.

Comment: As it appears that OP is expecting a true/false result for either condition, you might want to add an ELSE clause to handle the EXISTS check when it's false.

Comment: I edited my answer as I found some more bugs, also changed how you return value. I should work fine.

Comment: @Tim - `NOT EXISTS` doesn't force a table scan.

Answer (score 1):

One approach can be this :

```
USE [Database Name]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsFruitEatable] 
    @Fruit_Crate_ID int,
    @Fruit_ID int
AS
BEGIN 
declare @Return bit = 0
select @Return = Fruit_Eatable 
  from Table3
 where Table3.Fruit_Crate_ID = @Fruit_Crate_ID 
   and Table3.Fruit_ID = @Fruit_ID 
   and EXISTS (select *
                 from Table2
                where Table1.Fruit_Crate_ID = @Fruit_Crate_ID)

select @Return
END
```

Comment: I would think using an IF EXISTS statement would be easier than doing a sub-query in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @FilipDeVos - How so?  Additionally, I'm not sure the sub-query will work, since it's selecting from Table2 but the WHERE clause is referencing Table1 (unless SQL does an implicit join between Table1 and Table2).  Beyond that, SELECT * in the sub-query will not determine if the fruit is eatable or not, only if there's a row for it in that table.

Comment: There is no need for a join because the exists just needs to pop true when there is at least 1 record for the @Fruit_Create_ID. The alias is wrong "and Fruit_Eatable = 1" should be added though.